# Real data for Markov Chains

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I'm looking for real data for the application of some algorithms that involve applications of Markov chains and Power methods. What I need is a huge transition Matrix for some experimentation and testing, but I can't find this kind of matrix. Can someone help me, please?